# Is there a Node.js package that provides popup windows?

Tags: node.js

I need a popup window from a stand alone Node.js program.
Is there a package I can get that will let me do this?
I am *NOT* making a web server.
I am making a fairly trivial utility program that will count down then popup a window when it is done.

Comment: Wonder why I got -1 on this?  I looked around for a way to do it, and couldn't find one.  Background info: I figured a good way to learn javascript is make some stand alone utils that I would actually use instead of making some web pages.  I don't want to have to run in a browser, there is too much decoration around them (meaning too big of a window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) (formerly Node Webkit) which allows you to create desktop applications (with popups) using JavaScript and NodeJS.

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but it looks like it will be good enough.  Sorry I cannot mark this as the answer, because I would still like to know of package that can do it if there is one.

Comment: Node cannot create "windows" without something like Webkit which NW contains.

Comment: So are you saying it only runs in a sandbox and packages cannot add functionality that breaches that sandbox?  ( I was hoping packages had complete access to the system, sort of like a plugin )

Comment: No, what I'm saying is: NodeJS has no concept of a "window" and thus, cannot create them. If your target opsys any version of Windows that supports WinRT, you could use [NodeRT](https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT) to call the Windows native windowing API, but considering that WinRT is not cross-platform and isn't the most intuitive of APIs, you'd be far better off using NW, IMHO. ;)

Comment: You could use something like the `open` module and open the default browser.

Comment: Follow up: I am really happy using nw as was suggested.  It lets me make windows and with node-webkit installed lets me make them always on top if I need it.